# Check if file name contains string

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I have a function which I would like to activate only when the url starts in a particular format, but with variable endings.

```
    $actual_link =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 

    if ($actual_link == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/index.php") {
        select_imagex("SELECT * FROM page_image WHERE pageID = 1"); 
    }
    else if ($actual_link == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/") {
        select_imagex("SELECT * FROM page_image WHERE pageID = 1"); 
    }

    /* section which I have issues with */
    /* x = changing variable */
    else if ($actual_link == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/news.php/id=x") {
        echo "bob";
    } else {
        select_image("SELECT * FROM page_image WHERE pageID = ?"); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the link with variable `$x`. **Don't forget to set variable `$x`.**

```
$actual_link =  "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; 

if ($actual_link == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/index.php") {
    select_imagex("SELECT * FROM page_image WHERE pageID = 1"); 
}
else if ($actual_link == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/") {
    select_imagex("SELECT * FROM page_image WHERE pageID = 1"); 
}

/* section which I have issues with */
/* x = changing variable */

else if ($actual_link == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/news.php/id=".$x) {
    echo "bob";
} else {
    select_image("SELECT * FROM page_image WHERE pageID = ?"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could either check if the first 59 characters of the string are the same:

```
else if(substr(0, 59, $actual_link) == "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/news.php/id=" )
```

or you could check if the string contains the URL with strpos

```
else if(strpos($actual_link, "http://localhost:1234/WebDevelopment/Bathrooms/news.php/id=") !== false)
```

if you want to get `x` you can also get the substring that comes after the link:

```
$x = substr($actual_link, 59);
```